# 302 Found when running the Perl Script

Tags: perl, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use WWW::Facebook::API;
use WWW::Facebook::API::Auth;
use WWW::Facebook::API::Canvas;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP;

use CGI;                                # load CGI routines
$q = CGI->new;                          # create new CGI object
print $q->header,                       # create the HTTP header
  $q->start_html('Facebook App'),       # start the HTML
  $q->h1('Facebook Authentication'),    # level 1 header
  $q->end_html;                         # end the HTML

my $facebook_api      = '---------------';
my $facebook_secret   = '----------------------------';
my $facebook_clientid = '-----------------------------------';

my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(
    desktop     => 0,
    api_version => '1.0',
    api_key     => $facebook_api,
    secret      => $facebook_secret,

);

$client->app_id($facebook_clientid);
print $q->redirect( $client->get_login_url() );
```

In Web browser displayed as

```
Facebook Authentication
Status: 302 Found Location: http://www.facebook.com/login.php? api_key= -  ----------------&v=1.0
```

How to fix this CGI Problem. I am running this perl script in ubuntu apache server.

Answer (score 4):

You print your HTTP header here:

```
print $q->header
```

Then you print another HTTP header here:

```
print $q->redirect($client->get_login_url());
```

An HTTP message can have only one set of headers. If you're sending a 302 redirect, then there's no need to print any HTML either, so get rid of all of this:

```
print $q->header,                         # create the HTTP header
$q->start_html('Facebook App'),       # start the HTML
$q->h1('Facebook Authentication'),    # level 1 header
$q->end_html;                         # end the HTML
```

Comment: But when i am using the same code in the another machine[Which is having the low configuration] its working fine.  What is the reason behind this.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe you have different versions of modules or settings. Every time someone says "I'm using the same code ...", I find out they aren't. :)